# Ways of drawing out objects of different types

Tags: probability

There are 5 types of objects, each type has many and has the chance of 1/5 being drawn out. I want to find the probability that I can draw out all types in 5 draws.

Is it $1*4/5*3/5*2/5*1/5=5!/5^5$ or $1/C_4^9$? The logic of latter is finding (Number of solutions to $a+b+c+d+e=5$ given that all $\geq 1$)/(Number of solutions to $a+b+c+d+e=5$ given that all $\geq 0$).

How about if the number of total draws can be increased to $>5$? By (Number of solutions to $a+b+c+d+e=n$ given that all $\geq 1$)/(Number of solutions to $a+b+c+d+e=n$ given that all $\geq 0$), is the probability $=C_4^{n-1}$/$C_4^{n+4}$?

Answer (score 2):

Taking "many" to  mean infinite, the problem is equivalent to tossing a $5-$sided die repeatedly.

*First part*

The first solution is ok, the second using stars and bars doesn't give equiprobable outcomes

*Second part*

This becomes more complicated, we need to use inclusion-exclusion.
Again, stars and bars won't give the correct answer for the reason already explained.

There are $5^n$ total possible outcomes, of these, $4^n$ miss at least one type, $3^n$ miss at least two, and so on, thus$$Pr = \frac{5^n - \binom51 4^n +\binom52 3^n -\binom53 2^n + \binom54 1^n}{5^n}$$

Comment: Are you sure about this? Intuitively, there are $5!$ combinations containing all $5$ types, and $5^5$ combinations in total, so the probability is $\frac{5!}{5^5}$... right?

Comment: @barakmanos: If you are talking of the first part, I already said that the first solution is ok.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I missed that... thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos: If you put $n =5$ in the general formula, you will get (as you should), $\frac{5!}{5^5}$